# django like button with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a template where I have like link for my article :

```
<div id="voteUp">
<h4><a href="{% url "vote_up" article.id %}">Like {{article.up_vote}}</a></h4>
</div>
```

Here I want to increase the vote count for my article when user clicks it.
I have written view for it and it is working nicely.
But now I dont want to refresh the page.
I want to call it from ajax. Here is what I am doing.

```
<script>

$('#voteUp').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
           //type: "POST",
           url: "/service/vote/up/{{article.id}}",
           success: function(response) {
                  alert("success");
                  alert('Liked');
            },
            }
      }); 
})
```

I just want when the user click the like button it should be increased without refreshing the page.

When I see from firebug I dont see any javascript called.
Whats wrong in here ?
Thank you

Comment: May be you should track click on your link instead of parent div?

Answer (score 0):

valentjedi is right: `#voteUp` is targeting the `<div>`, but the click event will be on `<a>`.

Either you give an id to the `<a>` tag, or you should change your jquery selector.

You will also have to [prevent the default behaviour of the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2058072/3207406) (that is, open the page in the browser)

Comment: Ohk i have changed the id to <a> tag. but my page is being refreshed. Ajax is calling I can see it in firebug but page is being refreshed.

Comment: @aryan please learn your HTTP status codes - 301 is NOT an error, it's a redirect.

Comment: "but page is being refreshed" did you read about the default browser behavior? Did you add the `e` argument? Did you place the code at the right position? (**not** in the `success` callback)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="voteUp" href="{% url "vote_up" article.id %}">Like {{article.up_vote}}</a>

<script>
$('#voteUp').click(function(evt){
  $.ajax({
    //type: "POST",
    url: $(evt.currentTarget).attr("href"),
    success: function(response) {
      alert("success");
      alert("Liked");
    }
  });
  evt.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```